# O que significa #noqa em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As vezes encontro esse comentário em algum código Python: `#noqa`.

O que significa? É específico para Python?

Comment: NO Quality Assurance, basicamente diz pra linha ser ignorada por alguns programas que analisam código fonte.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Como vamos saber se nem o criador da linguagem sabe](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/476)? :P :D

Brincadeiras à parte, para a linguagem Python em si significa nada, é até mais específico que Python. Como pode ser visto no *link* acima é só um comentário como outro qualquer que tem ferramenta externa que entende a semântica de maneira especial. Pelo que foi dito lá é como o utilitário Flake8 ignora as recomendações da PEP8 em sua análise (outros podem ter adotado também).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 12):

O "No Q/A", ou seja, faz com que algumas ferramentas(flake8 e pycodestyle ) ignorem os erros contidos naquela linha específica.

É estilo o
`// eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define` do ESLint, o style guide JavaScript.

Comment: Vale citar que esses "erros" são na verdade inconsistências com os padrões de formatação definidos nessas ferramentas; não erros de sintaxe. Resumindo, se eu quero colocar um espaço em branco onde ele sugere não por, posso utilizar o `noqa` para omitir as mensagens de alerta sobre a formatação.